# setting up gradle plugin with DefaultTask to instantiate a class that renders react-native

Tags: react-native, gradle

I am trying to build a module with gradle that starts up a react-native app in a native app. Im following a guide that explains that a class extending from DefaultTask is responsible for the root behavior of the plugin. Going off of that, I want to do something with a file like this. [start react app class](https://github.com/ggsrivas/reactAndroidSDKDevApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/reactandroid/ggsrivas/com/reactandroiddev/MainActivity.java#L17) . Am I on the right track?

```js
public class DemoTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    public void renderRNSDK() {

    }
}
```